# Error SQL Server attempt to attach an auto-named database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\DB Report.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC

My config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" 
         connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\DB Report.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Help me please .. I have problem a few day

Comment: Please add your connection string info on your question. Try changing `AttachDBFileName` to absolute directory path, or use `Initial Catalog` and server name instead.